Are 30 inch vertical tracks long enough for 3 bookshelves?


Hi everyone! Basically I have two options for how to configure some track shelving for some "above headboard" bookshelves over my bed. would prefer to go with A, but eager to hear thoughts. A few things:

Would prefer option A if all things are equal, both because the install would be easier (I only have a step-ladder, and option B would require a bigger ladder to put up and take down) and also because it will make actually getting the books off the shelves easier... though if option B is significantly safer/structurally sound, I can always get a grabber tool for the highest shelf.

With option A it's not clear to me how many shelves I can put on the 30 inch track? In picture examples of track shelving I don't often see the top shelf beginning where the vertical track ends, if you see what I mean from the diagram. But also, if there's a slot for a standard there, surely it can be used? Idk, I'm an idiot.

If going with option B using 48" tracks, there'll be overhang since I want the shelves 12"ish inches apart. I'm hesitant to mount the 48" tracks lower down on the wall because I don't have a headboard, and don't want to rock the structural integrity of the thing by rubbing up against/bumping into the tracks while sitting up in bed. But if this is less of an issue than I think it is, lmk.

Possible installation issue with option B: I can't really move the Kallax shelving unit on the left side, and I can only move my bed forward about 20 inches ... not sure that would be enough clearance for a bigger ladder if I could find one to borrow (not a guarantee).

The books will be mostly paperbacks and secured with bookends. I've estimated on the very high end for load just to be safe, and included the weight of the shelves in that. The load'll probs be 30-50% less.

The far left and far right studs are protected by metal plates + are over outlets. I drilled into the stud next to one and it didn't have the metal plate, so I'm guessing the plated studs are just protecting electrical. I'm choosing not to mess with it, and since the hang track will be fastened to the studs, I think I can get away with having two vertical tracks off center. I could try to get a borescope and look in there but idk if it would be worth it.

My apartment also has a baseboard radiator running along the wall to the right (not the wall with the shelves). The heating is building-wide, so I'm guessing pipes for it may well run through this interior wall rather, than an exterior wall where the pipes might freeze. Hoping the risk of hitting a pipe with a 2” cabinet screw at this height (~60” from floor at lowest point) is low.

Does it matter hugely that this wall may not be structural/load bearing? (Not sure that's the right term). The building itself was built in 1910 but the renovation of it into 26 apartments was definitely more recent (sometime in last 50yrs). The building is two apartments wide and this is the wall that separates me from my neighbor. It's thick enough that I can't hear talking, but if she shuts a drawer up against the wall hard, I do feel it. The studfinder def detected studs though.

Considering I'll be sleeping under it, would I be an idiot not to hire a handyman, or is this something I can DIY?



Stud walls should be mounted/attached to the floor and ceiling structural members(joists), so load bearing or not, should hold the weight(possible corners were cut and only drywall ceiling holding the top, but hopefully rare).  Books can get heavy, so screwing into studs is recommended.

You're asking multiple questions here, at least some of which are subjective (and therefore off topic). Please see [ask] and the [help], then take the [tour]. Revise to simplify your question to one specific thing.

I've installed elfa vertical tracks for shelving before. Don't know how similar it is to yours, but I found it very easy as a DIY to have quite secure shelving.  (I was able to drill directly into studs.   I haven't had to rely on drywall anchors in any of my installations)
The vertical standards can be cut.   Possibly by whoever you purchase it from, or by you with a hacksaw.   So you could order the 48" ones and trim them to be just right for what you're trying to do.
The ones I've seen have no diagonal bracing, and only secure to the wall at the header.   So side loads on the shelving can make them swing unless you take extra steps to secure one or more standards at the bottom.   In places with earthquakes, they can move.   In California, I wouldn't sleep under shelves, regardless of how stable the shelf itself is.

The far left and far right studs are protected by metal plates + are over outlets. I drilled into the stud next to one and it didn't have the metal plate, so I'm guessing the plated studs are just protecting electrical. I'm choosing not to mess with it, and since the hang track will be fastened to the studs, I think I can get away with having two vertical tracks off center.

Having a plate would indicate why you couldn't fasten the hang track there because it interferes with the screw. But I don't understand why that would prevent the verticals from being where you want.   Note that your verticals will be forced into particular positions by the shelving.   The hardware that secures the shelves locks into the ends of the shelf.   So if you can't put the verticals where you want, you may not be able to attach the shelf.

Does it matter hugely that this wall may not be structural/load bearing?

No.  As long as it's standard stud framing, and you can hit the studs on the hang track, you should have plenty of strength.
